# Intercept Certificate Validation on MacOS

Tags: macos, ssl, kernel, keychain

All of the research I have done has not turned up anything useful.

I am trying to "intercept" or "detect" the validation of a certificate signers using Keychain on MacOS.

For instance, when Safari or Chrome (not firefox since it brings its own keystore) attempts to validate the signature of a certificate against the installed root CA's on the system. Is there a way to be notified of that check?

Assuming this would have to be a kext?

Resource I've found so far:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/keychain_services
https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1394363-sectrustevaluate
https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services

Comment: I don't have a good suggestion for where to find this, but I'm fairly sure a kext is not the way forward. The keychain and Secure Transport (Apple's TLS implementation) are both entirely implemented in userspace. I suspect you'd somehow have to intercept library calls to keychain services? I suggest checking the Webkit and/or Chromium source to see how the check is done, then keep digging from there.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, but I wonder if you found any user-space way to intercept the client-sign certificates. thanks !